# facebook profile image fetching error

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-login

This is my MainLogin.java activity coding for facebook login

```
public class MainLogin extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    Button login;
    ImageView pic;
    Facebook fb;
    TextView welcome;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_login);

        String APP_ID = getString(R.string.APP_ID);
        fb = new Facebook(APP_ID);
        login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.facebook_login);
        pic = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.user_pic);
        welcome = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.welcome);
        updateLoginState();

    }

    public void updateLoginState() {
        if(fb.isSessionValid()){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Logged In successflly2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            pic.setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE);

            JSONObject obj = null;
            URL img_url = null;

            try {
                String jsonUser = fb.request("me");
                obj = Util.parseJson(jsonUser);

                String id = obj.optString("id");
                String name = obj.optString("name");

                welcome.setText("Welcome"+name);

                img_url = new URL("http://graph.facebook.com/"+id+"/picture?type=small");
                Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(img_url.openConnection().getInputStream());
                pic.setImageBitmap(bmp);
            } catch (FacebookError e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }else{
            pic.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);
        }
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.facebook_login:
            if(fb.isSessionValid()){
                try {
                    fb.logout(getApplicationContext());
                    updateLoginState();
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }else{
                fb.authorize(MainLogin.this, new DialogListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) {
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onError(DialogError e) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "error",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
                        updateLoginState();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Logged in Successfully!",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onCancel() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Canceld",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

This app login successfully but in the `updateLoginState()` following error occurs . this is my logcat

```
    08-15 15:26:43.474: E/AndroidRuntime(16241): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
08-15 15:26:43.474: E/AndroidRuntime(16241):    at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1125)
08-15 15:26:43.474: E/AndroidRuntime(16241):    at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
08-15 15:26:43.474: E/AndroidRuntime(16241):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
08-15 15:26:43.474: E/AndroidRuntime(16241):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
08-15 15:26:43.474: E/AndroidRuntime(16241):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:70)
08-15 15:26:43.474: E/AndroidRuntime(16241):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:50)
08-15 15:26:43.474: E/AndroidRuntime(16241):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:340)
08-15 15:26:43.474: E/AndroidRuntime(16241):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:87)
08-15 15:26:43.474: E/AndroidRuntime(16241):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:128)
08-15 15:26:43.474: E/AndroidRuntime(16241):    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.openSocketConnection(HttpEngine.java:316)
08-15 15:26:43.474: E/AndroidRuntime(16241):    at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.makeSslConnection(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:461)
08-15 15:26:43.474: E/AndroidRuntime(16241):    at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:433)
08-15 15:26:43.474: E/AndroidRuntime(16241):    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:290)
08-15 15:26:43.474: E/AndroidRuntime(16241):    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:240)
08-15 15:26:43.474: E/AndroidRuntime(16241):    at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:292)
08-15 15:26:43.474: E/AndroidRuntime(16241):    at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:185)
08-15 15:26:43.474: E/AndroidRuntime(16241):    at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:271)
08-15 15:26:43.474: E/AndroidRuntime(16241):    at com.facebook.android.Util.openUrl(Util.java:219)
08-15 15:26:43.474: E/AndroidRuntime(16241):    at com.facebook.android.Facebook.requestImpl(Facebook.java:806)
08-15 15:26:43.474: E/AndroidRuntime(16241):    at com.facebook.android.Facebook.request(Facebook.java:732)
08-15 15:26:43.474: E/AndroidRuntime(16241):    at in.blogspot.pcnlap.sha_main_stream.MainLogin.updateLoginState(MainLogin.java:77)
08-15 15:26:43.474: E/AndroidRuntime(16241):    at in.blogspot.pcnlap.sha_main_stream.MainLogin.access$1(MainLogin.java:68)
08-15 15:26:43.474: E/AndroidRuntime(16241):    at in.blogspot.pcnlap.sha_main_stream.MainLogin$1.onComplete(MainLogin.java:145)
08-15 15:26:43.474: E/AndroidRuntime(16241):    at com.facebook.android.Facebook.onSessionCallback(Facebook.java:345)
08-15 15:26:43.474: E/AndroidRuntime(16241):    at com.facebook.android.Facebook.access$11(Facebook.java:326)
08-15 15:26:43.474: E/AndroidRuntime(16241):    at com.facebook.android.Facebook$1.call(Facebook.java:304)
08-15 15:26:43.474: E/AndroidRuntime(16241):    at com.facebook.Session$3$1.run(Session.java:1190)
08-15 15:26:43.474: E/AndroidRuntime(16241):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
08-15 15:26:43.474: E/AndroidRuntime(16241):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-15 15:26:43.474: E/AndroidRuntime(16241):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
08-15 15:26:43.474: E/AndroidRuntime(16241):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
08-15 15:26:43.474: E/AndroidRuntime(16241):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-15 15:26:43.474: E/AndroidRuntime(16241):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-15 15:26:43.474: E/AndroidRuntime(16241):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:821)
08-15 15:26:43.474: E/AndroidRuntime(16241):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584)
08-15 15:26:43.474: E/AndroidRuntime(16241):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

When I'm tries to fetch the profile image of the user use `updateLoginState()` the application itself crashes other than this application successfully logs into the facebook, Here i've been using the deprecated methods only. if any good and simple tutorial available for facebook login and something more then suggest me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your seeing NetworkOnMainThreadException, which is because your running an Asynchronous operation on the Main Thread. Android does not allow this.

Use AsyncTask to achieve this or enable StrickMode for your app.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to fetch the image on the UI thread. This is not compliant with android standards. You should use a Async task for example.

Find info here:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Or use this class:

```
private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
ImageView bmImage;

public DownloadImageTask(ImageView bmImage) {
    this.bmImage = bmImage;
}

protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
    String urldisplay = urls[0];
    Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
    try {
        InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
        mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return mIcon11;
}

protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
    bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
}}
```